# Change Date Order on X-Axis for Matplotlib chart with pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a figure for each exercise in 'Exercises' with the results of every participant in 'Participants' gains the Date. I have used two for-loops but unfortunately the dates on the x-axis are not in chronological order.

```
Participants = \['Yannick','Levin','Luca','Lars','Livio','Tim','Ryan','Schumi','Marc'\]
Exercises = \['100 Burpees for Time','Max. 1 Rep Benchpress','Max. Reps Muscle Ups','100 Turkish Get Ups','30 min. stationary bike','100 Pullups','500 Double Unders','Murph','1 hour row','5km run','Grace','Linda','Max Bar Hang','Amrap 14','1km Swim','5 Reps Deadlift','5 Reps Clean','Hero Workout "Miro"','The Schumi','2km row'\]

for exercise in Exercises:
    # define plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))  
    plt.title(exercise, fontsize = 18)

    for participant in Participants:
        # get Score and Date columns from pandas and plot them
        Score = data_csv.loc[(data_csv.Participant ==   participant)].loc[data_csv.Exercise == exercise]['Score']
        Date = data_csv.loc[(data_csv.Participant == participant)].loc[data_csv.Exercise == exercise]['Date']
        plt.plot(Date, Score, label = participant)
        plt.scatter(Date, Score, marker='o')
        plt.grid(axis = 'y')
        plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
    
        plt.legend(fontsize=14,bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.05))
        
    #plt.savefig('name1_{}.pdf'.format(name))
    plt.show()
```

And this is one of the plots it creates:

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIIRf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Md5.png)

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Your indentation level is off after the first for loop.  Is this how it is in your code, or did you make a typo here?  I could see how this may cause multiple figures to overlay each other...which may lead to multiple x-axis and the observed behavior.

Comment: That was a typo. I just corrected it to how it is in my code. But I still think that this is the problem. I do want to overlay multiple figures with different dates on the x-axis, however, I would need the dates in chronological order. Do you know if there is any way how to automatically sort the dates on the x-axis once you overlay them?

Answer (score 1):

If your date is in datetime format you can probably just sort your dates before you plot them.

```
Date = sorted(data_csv.loc[(data_csv.Participant == participant)].loc[data_csv.Exercise == exercise]['Date'])
```

Otherwise transform your dates into datetime by using:

```
data_csv["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data_csv["Date"])
```

Comment: I think I still would have the same problem because I am overlaying multiple figures, each with dates that are in chronological order but spread our over 2022. So the last date of my first figure does nod end where the date of the second figure starts. Is there any way how to sort them after I overlayed them?